# Show that $f(x, y)=(x+a \sin y, y+b \sin x)$ is a $C^1 $-diffeomorphism if $|ab| < 1$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

I've already proven that for any real $v$ the following function is continuous and strictly increasing :

$g(x) = x + a \sin(v - b \sin x)$

Therefore, it's bijective $\star$.

apparently it's supposed to help prove that $f(x, y)=(x+a \sin y, y+b \sin x)$ is bijective, one would then use the inverse function theorem to prove that it's a $C^1$-diffeomorphism but I can't seem to find a way to show the bijectivity of $f$ with or without using $\star$

any help would be appreciated.